# Android JUnit testing while executing OpenCV functionality on PC instead of android device

Tags: java, opencv, robotium, android-testing

I am trying to test an android app using Robotium in Eclipse android JUnit testing.

I want to capture screenshots at different stages using Robotium and process them using OpenCV library on my PC instead of the android device.

I have been reading forums on separating these two tasks. However, haven't been able to do so.

It would be great if anyone can shed some pointers on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To separate this two tasks, you need to realize (for example) REST client on android and server on the desktop.

1. Client should connect to server
2. Server pings client and client sends him screenshots. Perhaps, you will need to create separate thread in test.

Client should do the following:
When you need to take screenshot:

```
Object res = null;
res = new File(takeScreenShot(solo));
```

Then

```
    public static String takeScreenShot(Solo _solo) {
    solo = _solo;
    String dir = "/sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/";
    String fileName = "screenshot";

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(dir, fileName);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }

    solo.takeScreenshot(fileName);
    solo.sleep(2000);
    return "/sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/" + fileName + ".jpg";
    }
```

You need to send it

```
    service.sendScreen(file);
```

and in your service will do smthng like this:

```
public static JSONObject sendScreen(final File file) {

JSONObject res;
String response;

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(host + "/" + methodName);

    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();


entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));

httppost.setEntity(entity); 

    try{ 
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        res = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(response);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        res = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return res;
}
```

Here's example of code on C# to parse screenshot

```
    public void StepError(Stream stream)
    {
        var result = new DCStepErrorResponce();
        const string imageName = "file";
        string fullFileName = String.Empty;

        var parser = new MultipartFormDataParser(stream);

        if (parser.Files.Any(file => file.Name == imageName))
        {
            Stream data = parser.Files.First(file => file.Name == imageName).Data;

            string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "HFAutomationTesting", "Temp", "ScreenShots");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            do
            {
                string fileName = String.Format("{0:yy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_ffff}.jpg", DateTime.Now);
                fullFileName = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
            } while (File.Exists(fullFileName));

            var fileToUpload = new FileStream(fullFileName, FileMode.Create);
            byte[] bytearray = ToByteArray(data);
            fileToUpload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
            fileToUpload.Close();
            fileToUpload.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

You need just to realize rest server on C# and debug it.